# How to delete the oldest subdirectory?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, command-line, command

I have a directory with about 130 subdirectories in it.

Here's the main directory:

```
/home/data/all/
```

Subdirectories are like this:

```
/home/data/all/whatever
/home/data/all/test
/home/data/all/information
```

I want to have exactly 100 subdirectories in this main directory.  The oldest subdirectories (based on last modified date) should automatically be removed to make sure there's always exactly 100 directories.

Is there any way to do this with a one-liner?

Comment: You already have a nice answer [\[ here \]](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28947/25919).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to [\[ UL \]](http://unix.stackexchange.com) and already has an answer there as mentioned in Comment#1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls -A1td */ | tail -n +100 | xargs rmdir
```

You should test this first on **your backup directory,**